# hvplot.networkx does not render edges python

Tags: python, graph, networkx, hvplot

I created a graph from a street network using NetworkX. I can easily use nx.draw

```
plt.figure(figsize=(20, 18))
nx.draw(g, {n:[n[0], n[1]] for n in list(g.nodes)},  node_size=15)
plt.title('Major roads', size=15)
plt.show()
```

and it looks like

[image]

I would like to have a interactive visualisation, but when I use the `hvplot.networkx`, edges are not drawn.

```
hvnx.draw(g, pos={n:[n[0], n[1]] for n in list(g.nodes)} )
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option to try is to specify `node_size=0`:

```py
hvnx.draw(g, pos={n:[n[0], n[1]] for n in list(g.nodes)}, node_size=0)
```